# Querying for reaction counts

Tags: mysql

I have tables:

**Users**

```
user_id
name
```

**Posts**

```
post_id
user_id
post
image_path
```

**Reactions**

```
reaction_id
post_id
reaction
user_id
```

> Reactions have values of `{1: 'like', 2: 'dislike'}`

Now I want to get all the posts with the corresponding counts with each react.

So end result would be like:

```
{
post_id: 1,
post: "Hello World",
image_path: "public/upload_123.png",
likes: 23,
dislikes: 18,
my_reaction: 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by joining the tables with a `LEFT` join (just in case there are no reactions for a post) and then with conditional aggregation:

```
select p.post_id, p.post, p.image_path,
  sum(r.reaction = 1) likes,
  sum(r.reaction = 2) dislikes
from posts p left join reactions r
on r.post_id = p.post_id
group by p.post_id, p.post, p.image_path
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you sir!

Comment: sir how about if I want to get my current reaction? 

so it would turn out like 
```
{
post_id: 1,
post: "Hello World",
image_path: "public/upload_123.png",
likes: 23,
dislikes: 18,
my_reaction: 1
}
```

Comment: What is my current reaction? The last reaction (by reaction_id) or the last reaction of a specific user?

Comment: the user can only react once for every post. So I was thinking of a way to get what reaction the user put. But i got it now sir, thanks to your logic ^^

Answer (score 0):

Just run this code..

```
SELECT a.post_id, a.post,a.image_path,b.reaction,count(b.reaction) 
from posts a 
INNER join reactions b on a.post_id=b.post_id 
group by a.post_id, a.post,a.image_path,b.reaction
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the query. It goes as follows:

```
SELECT `posts`.`posts_id`, `users`.`user_id`, `posts`.`post`, `posts`.`file_path`, `posts`.`created_at`, `users`.`fname`, `users`.`mname`, `users`.`lname`, `r1`.`reaction`, IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(posts.file_path, '.', -1) IN ('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'), 'image', 'document') AS file_type, 
SUM(reactions.reaction = 1) AS likes, 
SUM(reactions.reaction = 2) AS hearts, 
SUM(reactions.reaction = 3) AS dislikes FROM `posts` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `posts`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id` LEFT JOIN `reactions` ON `reactions`.`posts_id` = `posts`.`posts_id` 
LEFT JOIN `reactions` AS `r1` ON `r1`.`posts_id` = posts.posts_id AND r1.user_id = 1 WHERE `posts`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
GROUP BY `posts`.`posts_id` 
ORDER BY `posts`.`created_at` DESC
```